# Access DoCMD.OpenReport acViewPreview never opens preview and freezes Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have spent several hours searching for a solution and troubleshooting.

Company I work for uses an Access DB for production purposes. Recently a coworker was asked to add a column to a table and form. Which works as intended. However, since that addition the button to print preview and print no longer works, in fact the dialog never pops up and Access itself freezes. CTRL-G still works.

The event for the print button is the same as it was prior to the addition of a new column...

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    
    'Open the report only if viewing the inventory not the lot transactions.
    If Form_frmViewInv_Sub2.Visible = True Then
        MsgBox "Report not available at this time - Please contact your administrator!", _
                vbInformation, DATABASE_NAME
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptInventory", acViewPreview
        
    End If
    
Exit_Procedure:  'Clean up and exit.
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    DisplayUnexpectedError Err.Number, Err.Description

    Resume Exit_Procedure
    Resume
    
End Sub
```

No errors, nothing in the event viewer, Access just freezes.

I feel like it's something simple, but Access is not my cup o' tea.

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Thank you.

Code for rptInventory...

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim frm As Form_frmViewInv
Dim frm2 As Form_frmViewInv_Sub1

On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    'Set the form object variables.
    Set frm = Form_frmViewInv
    Set frm2 = Form_frmViewInv_Sub1
    
    'Transfer the form attributes to the report.
    With Me
        .RecordSource = frm2.RecordSource
        .Filter = frm2.Filter
        .FilterOn = True
        .OrderBy = frm2.OrderBy
        .OrderByOn = True
    End With
    
    'Build the report title.
    Me.lblTitle1.Caption = "Company - " & _
                           Left(frm.lblTitle.Caption, InStr(1, frm.lblTitle.Caption, "(", vbTextCompare) - 3)
    Me.lblTitle2.Caption = frm.txtInvDate.Value

Exit_Procedure:  'Clean up and exit.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set frm = Nothing
    Set frm2 = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    DisplayUnexpectedError Err.Number, Err.Description

    Resume Exit_Procedure
    Resume
    
End Sub

Private Function ProdTypeDesc(ProdType As String) As String
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    'Get the product type description to display on the grouping.
    Select Case ProdType
        Case "0"
            ProdTypeDesc = "RM - Raw Material"
        Case "1"
            ProdTypeDesc = "FG - Finished Goods (BAT)"
        Case "2"
            ProdTypeDesc = "FG - Finished Goods (NER)"
        Case "3"
            ProdTypeDesc = "MU - MadeUp Recipe"
        Case "4"
            ProdTypeDesc = "PK - Packaging"
        Case Else
            ProdTypeDesc = "Unclassified Product Type"
    End Select

Exit_Procedure:  'Clean up and exit.
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    DisplayUnexpectedError Err.Number, Err.Description

    Resume Exit_Procedure
    Resume

End Function
```

UPDATE***
I was able to get it functioning by removing `ProdType IN('RM','MU','PK','FG','SP')` from rptInventory Data->Filter in design view. Though, I don't know why that worked.

Comment: So you tried to step debug? Problem is not reproducible and not enough info to analyze issue - would need to examine db - so not really suited to SO.

Comment: Stepping through yields the same results, with no indicators. I wish I better understood the `acViewPreview` process. What exactly happens step by step when that is called?

Comment: Is this a split design db? Can you rollback to version before the edits?

Comment: There is a front end client and a back end DB if that is what you mean. The old version was retained. It could be rolled back, but change was made to tables to include the new column in the BE and forms in the FE. Would like to retain those changes and figure out the freeze issue.

Comment: I am suggesting you roll back frontend and see if issue persists. If so, must be something wrong with backend. Is backend an Access? I doubt an answer can be provided here.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thank you for the suggestion. Too bad there wasn't a breakdown of the `acViewPreview` function. It does fire, I set a message alert just after it and that fired.

Comment: The problem seems to be the report or its data source. What happens if you open the data source / open the report in design view and switch to print preview?

Comment: The data source for the report is the form. I can open both in design view. I'll edit my post and include the code for rptInventory. I have compared the new code to the old code and they are identical.